# How to auto select another option in angularjs using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, 2-way-object-databinding, angularjs-ng-model

I have two select option and am using ng-options to get the data from json files. My concern is if a value is selected in first select, i need to automatically choose a corresponding value in the other select.
I am able to populate the data in the dropdowns. but am unable to connect the two. Please help.

Below is my code for first select:

```
<select ng-model="firstType"
                            ng-change="firstTypeChange()"
                            ng-options="firstValue as firstValue.value group by firstValue.group for firstValue in firstList" tabindex="1">
                            <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
```

And the second select is as follows:

```
<select ng-model="secondType"
                            ng-change="secondTypeChange()"
                            ng-options="secondValue as secondValue.value group by secondValue.group for secondValue in secondList"
                            tabindex="2">
                            <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
```

And this is my code from controller:

```
$scope.firstType = "";
$scope.secondType = "";
$scope.isFirstTypeShow = true;
$scope.isSecondTypeShow = true;

$scope.firstTypeChange = function() {
$scope.formType = $scope.firstType.formType;
 if ($scope.firstType.formType == 'inquiry') {
   $scope.isSecondTypeShow = false;
 } else if ($scope.firstType.formType != 'inquiry' || $scope.firstType.formType == null) {
   $scope.isSecondTypeShow = true;
 } else if ($scope.formType == 'known'){
   $scope.secondType.formType = 'existing';
 }
}
$scope.secondTypeChange = function() { $scope.secondFormType = $scope.secondType.formType;};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your second if statement

```
if ($scope.firstType.formType != 'inquiry' || $scope.firstType.formType == null) {
```

you already know from the first if statement this $scope.firstType.formType != 'inquiry' is true, which means this if statement is always true and the last if statement never gets reached.

The last if still wouldn't work though, you need to assign a value from your secondList to $scope.secondType to select the value. 
Check it out here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntj1k3km/)

```
$scope.firstTypeChange = function () {
    $scope.formType = $scope.firstType.value;   
    if ($scope.formType == 'inquiry') {
        $scope.isSecondTypeShow = false;
    } else if ($scope.formType == null) {
        $scope.isSecondTypeShow = true;
    }
    else if ($scope.formType == 'known') {
        $scope.secondType = $filter('filter')($scope.secondList, {value:'existing'})[0];
        $scope.isSecondTypeShow = true;
    }
    else {
        $scope.isSecondTypeShow = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add watch on first select item. And then based on the value selected in first item set the default value for the second selected item. Let me know if you jsfiddle example for this

Comment: so you mean ng-change does not work? Because am essentially changing the value based on the click. right? Am a newbie to angularjs world. So bear with me.